# Jquery AJAX call in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

we have asp.net mvc application, where we have to upload file of more than 20MB, i would like to run file upload process in the background using jquery ajax as user wouldn't need to wait for long time and once process is completed we would send email to user on upload details.
Code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ReviewSampleUpload/FilterSamplingLoans',
    async: true,

    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

i am able to hit the method but browser waits until the method completes execution, how to run this method at background so that user can do other operations.

Comment: You have to do a asynchronous operation in ASP.NET using a thread.

Comment: i tried that but unfortunately it did not work when i deployed on server, please see code below :

     Thread newThread = new Thread(() => loanResult1 = rep.filterSamplingLoans(dtLoans, model.ReviewId, (int)TempData["LoanCount"]));
            newThread.IsBackground = true;
            newThread.Start();

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? It is a file upload plugin for jQuery. User can still do other ajax tasks while they are waiting:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

If you want to allow user to navigate away the page, you may need to use a trick. The idea is to use `<iFrame>` to include your jQuery Upload Page separately. It is quite hard though.

The other idea you can try is to ask user to install your own downloader application like what [Microsoft File Transfer Manager](http://transfers.one.microsoft.com/ftm/default.aspx?target=ts) is doing. Then the tool at client computer will keep up the download progress for you.

Comment: my requirement is to upload a file of more than 20MB and run this process at background so that user need not wait for long time.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Could you just try to use <iframe>?

Comment: currently we dont bother about download progress, what we would like to achieve is , running a long process at background so that user can perform other stuff. I have tried using thread but it does not work once we deploy application on test server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of these depending on your need:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
Demo: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Or

http://www.dropzonejs.com/

We have used both in our MVC projects and they work perfectly.